# How to convert numbers in a string to underline as output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to complete a homework task and I am a little bit lost with it. I need to write a program using python where I need to enter a string and then output the string. Simple enough, but my task requires if the string has any numbers, the output will print underline instead of the number " _ ".

- Example.

input a string: hello I am 7 years old.

(REQUIRED Output: hello I am _ years old.)

So far this Is the current code i have.

```
string =input("Input a string? ")

print("Output:",string)
```

Could you please help me understand how this is achieved as I am fairly new to python.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You may want to look into `.isdigit()`.

Comment: i am simply trying to write a program that when a digit appears in a string the output reads the string but changes the digit to a " _ " underscore in place of the digit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Regex to trade out the numbers for anything.

```
#first I import the module
import re

#then I ask for a string
inputstring = input("Input a string? ")

#here I am taking the string and using regex. the \d does all numbers 0-9 and replaces them with the next argument which is an underscore,finally the input string is placed as the last argument.

finalstring = re.sub('\d', '_', inputstring)

#printing the final edited string
print(finalstring)
```